# Refactoring: Service objects in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I have a great working timesheet application. Now everything is running fine, it's refactoring time! Especially some views are really complicated. So I want to start using decorators for instance to clean them up.

Another thing is that I use a fair amount of service objects. While they are great and keep my models clean, using them in my views is not want I want. I'm looking for some refactoring advice here. Let's consider the following fragment of view code:

```
  .row
    .span12#timesheet
      - days = @timesheet_builder.get_days_in_month

      %table.table.days
        %tbody
          - (1..days).each do |day_nr|
            - activity_date = Date.new(@timesheet.year, @timesheet.month, day_nr)

            - if @timesheet_builder.is_workday?(day_nr)
              - day_type = "workday"
            - else
              - day_type = "non_workday"

            %tr.day(class=day_type)
              %td.date{ "data-title" => "#{I18n.t('.timesheet.day_nr')}" }
                .day_abbr= @timesheet_builder.get_day_name(day_nr)
                .day_nr= day_nr
```

What you see is a great TimesheetBuilder service object to get days in a month and checking if a day is a workday. Based on the result a line in a table gets a different color or other markup.

It works great, but how can I refactor this to make the view simpler? Can I use service objects in decorators?

Comment: I was looking at Cells (http://cells.rubyforge.org) which seem interesting. Any opinion on that?

Comment: `- (1..days).each do |day_nr|` => `- days.times do |day_nr|`

Answer (score 2):

Go with rails convention and stick them in a helper:

`module TimeSheetHelper  #automatically included within TimeSheet views
    def work_day_class(day)
      @timesheet_builder.is_workday?(day_nr) ? "workday" : "non_workday"
    end
  end`

Meanwhile.. back in your view:

`...
  %tr.day(class=work_day_class(day_nr))
  ...`

Answer (score 2):

Being a seasoned Rails developer I tend to dislike Rails helpers. When a number of helpers grows it tends to become a mess. But Your idea is correct - use intermediate objects to encapsulate Your business logic. You can either go by creating Your own solution, like [here in Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch)
Or You can use some ready made library like draper, see these for more info:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper
https://github.com/drapergem/draper

I feel like that using approach You suggest is a better OOP/OOD solution than making garbage inside helpers. Another plus is, I find that testing logic encapsulated inside class is a bit easier and cleaner than testing a module.

Comment: I agree with you about the helpers, I don't like them either. Instead of presenters or decorators I really like the approach of Cells.